# How to develop program which have less time complexity as possible?

Tags: data-structures, time

How to develop programs which has less time complexity as possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proven method to come up with the optimal algorithm for a given problem.

There are many problems for which is likely the world has not come up with the most efficient algorithm yet.

For example: what is the algorithm with the best time complexity for [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication)? At the time of writing no one knows what that theoretical best time complexity would be, let be there is someone who has designed an algorithm with that time complexity.